# Cloud Compute Engine VS VPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

Today I set up my first VM instance on Google Cloud Platform.
I wanted to install a simple lampp server with apache, php and MySQL.
And this is what I have done (ssh and a bunsh of apt-get install).

Everything works fine!

Now I heard that these instances are suppose to be scalable, which means if I have 100,000 http requests per second on my server it shouldn't lag.

So why do I need to select the RAM to install on my VM instance (shouldn't I pay according to the resources my VM use)?

Because I chose 2Go but will my instance be able to serve the 100,000 http request per s?

If not, what is the point to choose a VM instance instead of a VPS or dedicated server (because I can also choose my RAM on these solutions)?

Comment: There is almost no difference between a VPS and a cloud VM instance, but with a cloud VM you also get your own network space with the VPC. And you can use a full cloud VM instance e.g. bare metal and that is more or less the same as a "dedicated server".

Comment: Please read the following links. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask AND https://www.codementor.io/@matrixkavi/6-mistakes-to-be-avoided-while-asking-questions-on-stackoverflow-y8ye5sz62